# says no error found, does no file transfer

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, linux-mint

In Nautilus, copying files from my computer to my pendrive works.

LuckyBackup says no error found, but does no file transfer.

My Python script worked until I had Música instead of Music. WIthout saying the coding, I get an error message containing ASCII. With Unicode, I get an error message containing BOM. With UTF-8, I don't get an error message, but no files are transferred.

My Python script runs `rsync -rupogtv directory1 --delete directory2` lots of times.

How to make my computer sync with my pendrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the --delete option with all the others before the two directory names.